# How to change the way a ViewController's NavigationBar animates in during presentation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uinavigationcontroller

How can I change the way the Navigation Bar animates so that instead of animating down from the top, it slides in with the rest of the view from the right (see animation below).  I know I can use a Presentation Controller and Animation Controller, but only know how to modify how a ViewController presents itself, not the Navigation Bar.

[image: animation]

Comment: You mean, using `modalTransitionStyle`?

Comment: @ElTomato no, tried each type of transition style for both the navigationController and viewController, and neither changed the way the navigation bar animates.